# Suma en tiempo real Textbox

Tags: c#, windows-forms

como puedo realizar una multiplicacion en tiempo real de dos textbox y mostrar el resultado en un tercer textbox, lo estoy haciendo de esta manera pero no sale el resultado.

```
private void txtPrecioUnitario_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtPrecioUnitario.Text.Contains('.'))
        {
            if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }

            if (e.KeyChar == '\b')
                   {
                e.Handled = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }

            if (e.KeyChar =='.' || e.KeyChar =='\b')
                      {
                e.Handled = false;
            }
        }
        int total;
        total = int.Parse(txtPrecioUnitario.Text) * int.Parse(txtCantidad.Text);
        txtTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(total.ToString());

    }

    private void txtCantidad_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtCantidad.Text.Contains('.'))
        {
            if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }

            if (e.KeyChar == '\b')
            {
                e.Handled = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }

            if (e.KeyChar == '.' || e.KeyChar == '\b')
            {
                e.Handled = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: suma]

Comment: Al parecer lo estas haciendo el evento en el `txtTotal`, el evento deberia de ser en el `txtPrecioUnitario`.

Comment: @J.Castro yo creo que en los 2 `txtTotal` y `txtCantidad`

Comment: asi es lo estoy haciendo en el evento txtotal ya lo cambie al txtpreciounitario y me marca este error(System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format), el evento txtcantidad y txtpreciounitario solo puede escribir numeros.

Comment: @GabrielJeremyRodriguezRiver yo igual lo pienso pero la idea es hacerle ver en que esta mal y el lo adacte a sus necesidades..

Comment: yo crearia un evento que multiplicase cantidad x precio unitario y lo dejase en Total, en ese evento tambien comprobaria que ambos campos tienen un texto numerico. Luego añadiria ese evento a los dos validates de Cantidad y Precio Unitario y ya estaria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quizas si cambia el evento que dispara la funcion:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya que tiene 3 campos de texto, debe colocar el evento en el campo 3 "txtTotal" y este puede ser foco al entrar. Para evitar errores asegures que  el recorrido de los campos sea tal que "txtTotal" sea el ultimo. Así cuando llenen los dos anteriores encontrara los datos necesarios. (mas las validaciones y captura de excepciones

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si me funciono de esta manera solamente un pequeño detalle, el tercer campo de texto debe estar deshabilitado, aqui solamente funciona cuando el campo de texto esta habilitado y selecciono la casilla por eso, como le haria para que funcione sin seleccionar la casilla

Comment: @Daniel Y si coloca el campo de texto total como de solo lectura, de esa manera podrá obtener el foco y dispara el evento.

Comment: gracias me funciono de esa manera pero cuando pongo una de las casillas o las dos me marca error de exception no controlada

Comment: @Daniel Es necesario que haga validación de datos. Te lo había mencionado en la respuesta, Debe verificar que los datos sean validos,  del tipo adecuado. Sugiero que tome los datos por aparte, los valide y si son correctos ahí si realice la operación. La operación de calculo dentro de un Try Cath. Mira en Google hay buenos ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

double texb1 = 0, texb2 = 0;

```
    public void suma(double n1, double n2)
    {
        double sum = n1 + n2;
        textBox3.Text = sum.ToString();  
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        texb1 = Double.Parse (textBox1.Text.ToString());
        suma(texb1, texb2);
    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        texb2 = double.Parse(textBox2.Text.ToString());
        suma(texb1, texb2);
    }
```

podría ser así no importa en que lugar insertes los datos ya que el evento los disparas al teclear un carácter y es necesario meter algo para que valides que solo son números espero te sirva saludos